# WooCommerce codex : How to create an order from an existing cart (wc_create_order)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am creating a plugin that handles the full checkout for a WooCommerce cart.
It will do the payment and shipping and I simply need to then programatically create the order correctly in Woo Commerce.

I know I want to use wc_create_order(),
is there something I can then do to fill the order details from the current WC()->cart info?

And, as a 2nd part to this question, I will have a shipping address, how do I add that to the newly created order?

Comment: You should look in [**`process_checkout()`** function core code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#350) … You will find all the detailed process there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
$cart = WC()->cart;
$checkout = WC()->checkout();
$order_id = $checkout->create_order(array());
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
update_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', get_current_user_id());
$order->calculate_totals();
$order->payment_complete(); 
$cart->empty_cart();
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178900/woocommerce-codex-how-to-set-the-user-customer-on-an-order) helped with the setting the user id part.

Comment: I just used this portion of this 

```
$cart = WC()->cart;
$checkout = WC()->checkout();
$order_id = $checkout->create_order();
```
in order to create an order id whilst still on the cart page. This allowed me to update order meta details from the cart page just before actual checkout. Thanks!

Comment: Note for reviewers: edit accepted with dev_masta's code. Please delete this comment afterwards.