# WooCommerce codex : how to set the user/customer on an order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing a WooCommerce Plugin that takes care of payment and delivery.
Right now I am at the point of creating an order based on the current shopping cart.
That all works fine getting the items and costs correct, the only **problem is that the order shows as being made by "Guest"**, instead of by the currently logged on user (even though the correct email address for that user is on the order).

Here is my code :

```
    $cart = WC()->cart;
    $checkout = WC()->checkout();
    $order_id = $checkout->create_order();
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->user_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_customer_id', get_current_user_id() );
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->payment_complete(); 
    $cart->empty_cart();
```

Here is what I see in the backend after running this :

[image]

---

**Why is the order placed as "Guest" instead of the user that placed the order?**
**And how do I get to have the correct user attached?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will need to add `_customer_user` to post_meta table with order ID and meta value should be the user ID which you want to link to this order.

I hope that this will help you:

```
update_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', get_current_user_id());
```

Now, as we the answer is 6 years old - woocommerce has added class for this lately. You can do it like this now:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order->set_customer_id(get_current_user_id());
```

Comment: You are amazing - thank you so much - if I hadn't tried so many different things before posting this question I wouldn't have believed there isn't a sensibly named wrapper for this code on the WC order or checkout class , a  ->setCustomer() function, or just adding them onto the order by default seems even more logical to me.  Anyways - this worked - I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! :)

Answer (score 6):

OR

use user/customer id(create a customer/user before place order) in `wc_create_order();`

eg: `$order = wc_create_order(array('customer_id' => $user));`

this code fine for me!